# Spring - RestTemplate : java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, android, rest, runtimeexception

I developed an application client side. I make rest call. When I do too many calls, my application crash. I understand that it's a problem of concurrency but I do not know how to fix the issue.

Here is the log error:

```
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207): Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:569)
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$AcceptHeaderRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:541)
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:593)
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:474)
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:453)
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:358)
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at com.bpc.inno.nao.controller.services.NaoServicesClient$ServiceRequest.doInBackground(NaoServicesClient.java:138)
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-25 15:18:14.060: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):     ... 5 more
```

The error is there

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected K doInBackground(T... params) {
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(
                    new MediaType("application","xml"),
                    new MediaType("text", "xml")));
    HttpEntity<T> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<T>(
                    params[0], requestHeaders);
    try {
        ResponseEntity<K> response = mRestTemplate.postForEntity(
                        mUri, requestEntity, mResponseType);
                return response.getBody();
    } catch (ResourceAccessException ex) {
                Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
        if (cause != null && cause instanceof ConnectTimeoutException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Request Timeout");
        }
        mError = true;
        return null;
    }
}
```

I do not know how to fix it. Do you?

Comment: block the UI while executing the task, for example show a progressDialog..

Comment: From `stackTrace` it looks as this line is faulty: `ResponseEntity<K> response = mRestTemplate.postForEntity(mUri, requestEntity, mResponseType);` Is there a chance that some other `thread` is working on the same params?

Comment: I think you are looking in the wrong place.  The "concurrent" in the error message may not involve a second thread.  It means that you are iterating over an ArrayList and that you change the contents of that list while you are iterating.

Comment: What version of spring-rest ?

Comment: I use 1.0.1.RELEASE of spring framework

Answer (score 2):

After a quick look into [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-android/blob/1.0.x/spring-android-rest-template/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.java). The relevant line is here :

```
for (HttpMessageConverter<?> messageConverter : getMessageConverters())
```

So it seems that you are changing the messageConverters of `mRestTemplate` and at the same time (i.e. in another AsyncTask) : you are iterating on them.

My advices :

- review your calls to `mRestTemplate.setMessageConverters(...)` to see you can fix something there.
- if the problem is still there : don't share your restTemplate between threads (i.e. asyncTasks)

Note that there is a fix in trunk that will probably solve your problem with the next release : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/1222ca38fb46a5c461fa41d2d4383469d10a2ede

Comment: Thank you a lot ben75. I will try that. 
I will try to block the UI in a second way.
Thanks you guys

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the `requestEntity` that you create from `params[0]` is not modified elsewhere--perhaps some place after the async call in `NaoServicesClient`.

Also:

- Contrary to @ben75's answer, Your `ConcurrentModificationException` error is indicative of another thread in your application trying to alter a `List` in the `RequestEntity` passed to `mRestTemplate`.  Since you are processing asynchronously, another thread accessing the entity could be trying to modify the entity while the `mRestTemplate` is concurrently trying to process the entity.
- For asynchronous `RestTemplate` processing, you should be using at least version 3.2.x or ideally version 4.x of the Spring Framework.  Many APIs have been deprecated and fixed since 1.x and 2.x; I strongly recommend [upgrading](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Aorg.springframework%20a%3Aspring-core).
- Also contrary to @ben75's answer, Spring recommends you share your `RestTemplate` between threads as it is [thread-safe](https://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate):

> Conceptually, it is very similar to the JdbcTemplate, JmsTemplate, and the various other templates found in the Spring Framework and other portfolio projects. This means, for instance, that the RestTemplate is thread-safe once constructed

- You should **not** be re-configuring your `MessageConverter`s after Bean instantiation (if indeed you are actually doing this).  The [Spring Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-message-conversion) has concise examples.